# Get List<String> while concat 3 Streams from lists of different objects

Tags: java, spring, collections, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Person {  
    public List<BaseballPlayer> baseballPlayers;    
    public List<MmaFighter> mmaFighters;    
    public List<RugbyPlayer> rugbyPlayers;  
}
```

In every object player there is String property for his id. I am trying to collect all ids in list which I do

```
List<String> baseballPlayersIds = person.baseballPlayers.stream()
.map(s -> s.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());  

List<String> mmaFightersIds = person.mmaFighters.stream()
.map(s -> s.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());  

List<String> rugbyPlayersIds = person.rugbyPlayers.stream()
.map(s -> s.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

baseballPlayersIds.addAll(mmaFightersIds);
baseballPlayersIds.addAll(rugbyPlayersIds);
```

Now I am trying to simplify things and improve logic by using Stream.concat()

```
Stream<List<BaseballPlayer>> baseballPlayersIdsStream =  Stream.of(person.baseballPlayers);    
Stream<List<MmaFighter>> mmaFightersIdsStream = Stream.of(person.mmaFighters);
Stream<List<RugbyPlayer>> rugbyPlayersIdsStream = Stream.of(person.rugbyPlayers);       

Stream<List<? extends Object>> personStream = Stream.concat(baseballPlayersIdsStream, Stream.concat(mmaFightersIdsStream, rugbyPlayersIdsStream));
```

but I cannot figure should I use generics for type of new stream that comes out of the 3 streams? Also tried to create parent class for all 3 classes to use in the stream diamand instead of Object. This personStream is in doubt.

Comment: Do `BaseballPlayer`, `MmaFighter`, and `RugbyPlayer` all implement a common interface that defines an abstract `getId()` method?

Comment: @JacobG. They don't

Comment: Are those classes allowed to be modified so that they can implement a common interface?

Comment: If this is a solution and there are no other ways it is possible to modify classes, but if there is other way I would try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<String> allIds = Stream.of(
    person.baseballPlayers.stream().map(p -> p.getId()),
    person.mmaFighters.stream().map(p -> p.getId()),
    person.rugbyPlayers.stream().map(p -> p.getId()))
    .flatMap(s -> s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or

```
List<String> allIds = Stream.of(
    person.baseballPlayers.stream().map(BaseballPlayer::getId),
    person.mmaFighters.stream().map(MmaFighter::getId),
    person.rugbyPlayers.stream().map(RugbyPlayer::getId))
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can also use `Function.identity()` instead of `s -> s`

Answer (score 2):

If you implement a common interface in all classes:

```
interface Team {
    String getId();
}
```

You can use the following code:

```
List<BaseballPlayer> baseballPlayers = ...;
List<MmaFighter> mmaFighters = ...;
List<RugbyPlayer> rugbyPlayers = ...;

List<String> identfiers = Stream.of(baseballPlayers, mmaFighters, rugbyPlayers)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(Team::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it's like the very first question under the question itself and the OP said - this is not an option

Comment: Look at their last comment: 'but if there is other way I would try it '.

Comment: indeed, missed that